# Kotlin Closable and SQLiteDatabase on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I use this code in my project

```
fun getAllData(): List<Data> = writableDatabase.use { db ->
    db.query(...)
}
```

It executes successfully on Lollipop devices, but on pre-Lollipop it throws a ClassCastException

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase cannot be cast to java.io.Closeable
```

Probably because it's Java 1.6 and doesn't have the try-with-resources feature, but I'm not sure.

So why do I have this exception and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with *try-with-resources* and is simply an incompatible dependency issue between the compiled code and the runtime environment.

The problem is at compile time `SQLiteDatabase` implements the interface `Closeable` and later you swap this out for another implementation that does not.  But the code is compiled already and doesn't know about this change.

When you call a function / method, all parameters are checked to make sure they are the correct types, this usually being handled by the JVM.  For inline and extension functions the Kotlin compiler inserts a type check to make sure it is operating on the correct type, and for this specific inline function the receiver of the function is defined as being `Closeable`.  Here is the method signature:

```
inline fun <T : Closeable, R> T.use(block: (T) -> R): R { ... }
```

So the compiler inlines a type check on `writableDatabase` as follows (*in bytecode*):

```
CHECKCAST java/io/Closeable
```

So at this point, the implementation of `SQLiteDatabase` must forever implement the `Closeable` interface or the compiled code will fail.  By swapping to an older version of Android where this is no longer true, you break the contract and cause the exception.  There is no way the compiler can do anything different.  It would be the same as me swapping out a JAR in any JVM application to one with radically different implementations after I've already compiled my code.  Changing Android versions basically swaps all the JARs.

**What you can do to work around this problem** is write your own `use` function specifically for the `SQLiteDatabase` class if all versions have a `close` method (*copied and modified from the Kotlin stdlib `use` function*):

```
inline fun <T : SQLiteDatabase, R> T.use(block: (T) -> R): R {
    var closed = false
    try {
        return block(this)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        closed = true
        try {
            close()
        } catch (closeException: Exception) {
            // eat the closeException as we are already throwing the original cause
            // and we don't want to mask the real exception
       }
        throw e
    } finally {
        if (!closed) {
            close()
        }
    }
}
```

Now the inline typecheck will be `CHECKCAST android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase` which will always succeed.

Comment: Yes, you are right. On pre-lollipop `readableDatabase is Closeable` returns false, while on lollipop returns true. I wonder, why there is no documentation that SQLiteDatabase implements Closeable interface since API19. But anyway, thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but where do you put this?

Comment: So are you saying that it's not safe to use `.use { ... }` when we support old versions of Android? E.g, from 14 to 28 API